# VBA Powerpoint Slide Transition to ignore animation time

Tags: vba, animation, powerpoint, transition

Have a large slide show with lots of images, which I would like to have animating slowly.
But want a consistent transition time.
Unfortunately cannot find a way to get Powerpoint Transition time to be prioritized over slide animation time. Current code I'm using below to try to set transition times.

```
    Sub slideAdvance()

With ActivePresentation.Slides.Range.SlideShowTransition
     'make sure the next slide will be shown automatically.
    .AdvanceOnTime = msoTrue
     'Set "advance to next slide" time (in seconds).
    .AdvanceTime = 5

End With

ActivePresentation.SlideShowSettings.AdvanceMode = ppSlideShowUseSlideTimings

End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What happens that shouldn't?  But it may help to understand that PowerPoint will always prioritize animation timings over slide advance timing. That is, if you have an animation or sequence of animations on a slide, PPT won't advance to the next slide until they're done, regardless of the chosen transition time.

Comment: that is exactly the problem. Slide Transitions should be 5 seconds. Need a way to set animations speeds that are slower (20 seconds in some cases). So, need a way to force the progression of a slide even if the individual animation hasn't finished.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't believe you can do this. You'll have to adjust the duration of your animations such that they finish before your 5 second transition time.